# Yeoman: EACCES error running karma unit test for Angularjs

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm following the sample Yeoman workflow listed on yeoman.io:

```
npm install -g generator-angular generator-karma  # install generators
yo angular                     # scaffold out a AngularJS project
bower install angular-ui       # install a dependency for your project from Bower
*grunt test                     # test your app
grunt server                   # preview your app
grunt                          # build the application for deployment
```

Everything works great except the `grunt test` command:

```
C:\yeoman2>grunt test

(logging omitted for brevity)

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Starting connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
Fatal error: listen EACCES
```

I haven't updated my gruntfile or made any other modifications to the configs. Has anyone seen this EACCESS error before? I'm on Windows 8, with a fresh node install.

Answer (score 37):

This was happening because the karma server was running on port 8080. I changed it (in karma.conf.js) to 9999 and all is well.

Comment: I tried this and it worked too... Why does 9999 work so much better than 8080?

Comment: Do you have something else running on port 8080?

Comment: Only Karma as far as I know... did you?

Comment: This did the trick, wish the error message was a little more descriptive, something like: `error binding to port 8080`.